# ajaxが動作しない

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

以下のajaxが動作しないのですが、原因がわかる方いらしゃいますでしょうか。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="" class="img_check" name="img_check">
            <input type="text" class="img_check_form" name='img_check_form' placeholder="画像のURLを入力">
            <input type="button" value="チェックする" id="img_check_btn" name="img_check_btn"> 
        </form>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function(){
                $("form.img_check").submit(function(event) {
                    alert("alert");
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var val = $(this).children("input[name='img_check_form']").val();
                    $.ajax({
                        type:'POST',
                        url:'img_check.php',
                        data:{"contents": val},
                        success: function(data) {
                        alert(data);
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

img_check.php

```
<?php
    echo $_POST["content"];
```

宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="button" value="チェックする" id="img_check_btn" name="img_check_btn">
```

`input[type="button"]` をクリックしてもフォームの送信は行われず、submitイベントも発生しません。typeをsubmitに変更するか、submitイベントではなくclickイベントなどを使う必要があります。

参考 [<INPUT type="button">－HTMLタグリファレンス](http://www.htmq.com/html/input_button.shtml)